# Spark Driver process not terminating on Kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, hadoop-yarn

**Problem**: Spark driver process on Kubernetes doesn't terminate after the main method has completed execution and the Spark context has been stopped. I'm trying to migrate our current Spark Job on yarn to Kubernetes.

The termination of a JVM process is initiated by the JVM shutdown sequence, which is triggered in one of two ways:

- All non-daemon threads finish execution.
- System.exit method is called explicitly.

To identify the potential threads causing the issue, I printed a list of non-daemon threads running at the end of the main method.

**Findings on Kubernetes**: The list of non-daemon threads running on the Kubernetes Spark driver at the end of the main method included:

- main
- OkHttp kubernetes.default.svc (Run by K8s, terminated after stopping Spark context)
- OkHttp kubernetes.default.svc Writer (Run by K8s, terminated after stopping Spark context)
- Several *user threads*.

**Findings on YARN**: The list of non-daemon threads running at the end of the main method in the YARN Spark driver included:

- main
- Driver(this is the application master thread)
- Several *user threads*(same as K8s).

Interestingly, despite the presence of these *user threads* in both environments, the YARN JVM terminates while the Kubernetes one doesn't.

**On YARN**: When we run Spark in cluster mode on YARN, Spark starts the driver JVM with an instance of the ApplicationMaster class. The ApplicationMaster then invokes your Main class in a separate thread (which may subsequently create additional threads). However, the ApplicationMaster waits only for the Main thread to finish. This can be seen in the following code snippet from the ApplicationMaster class:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/8212d6f87c658ade3a87a12dbbb10e9c212fe4e7/resource-managers/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/ApplicationMaster.scala#L934
`ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction[Unit]() { override def run(): Unit = System.exit(master.run()) })`

Here, master.run() invokes your main class and waits for it to finish, then calls System.exit, which triggers the JVM shutdown sequence.

I couldn't find anything similar that is happening on Kubernetes.

I wanna know if this is this expected behavior on YARN ?
Should we do system.exit() in our user main class or gracefully shut down all user threads ?